# Typescript Invalid date with Ionic 3 simulator and Firefox

Tags: angular, datetime, typescript, ionic3

I have this function with MomentJs

```
      CreateFormat(date: string, time: string): string {
            let now = moment(date + " " + time, "YYYY-MM-DD H:m:s z").toDate();
            return moment(now, "YYYY-MM-DD H:m:s z").format("HH:mm");
          }
```

I got this result : 7:39 pm
i want to display it like this 19:39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using [**momentJs**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/) with your `Ionic 3` app.Then you won't have any browser specific errors like you have now.

> npm install moment

*.ts*

```
import moment from 'moment';

let now = moment().format('LLLL');
```

**Update:**

```
 moment("02:00 PM", "h:mm A").format("HH:mm")  // "14:00"
```

Comment: I got 'invalid date'

Comment: Check this `moment("02:00 PM", "h:mm A").format("HH:mm")  // "14:00"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this
` {{start_timestamp | date:'HH:mm a'}}

Answer (score 0):

in ts file start_timestamp = 1500536460;

print like this in html `<p class="timeLabel">{{start_timestamp | date:'YYYY-MM-DD H:m:s z'}}</p>`

Comment: You can **edit** your previous answer.No need to put 2 answers.